# ArrayList para String com split

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Estou tentando quebrar o seguinte `ArrayList` com uma `String`:

```
  ArrayList<Funcionario> funcionarios = new ArrayList();
```

Mas quando instancio o objeto, adiciono os valores lá dentro através do meu método e tento usar o `split`, o compilador sublinha o `.split` em vermelho e dá erro. Estou tentando separar as informações por um espaço `" "`.

```
Funcionario func = new Funcionario(); //Instancio o obj
func.cadastrar();  //CHama o método que lê o teclado
funcionarios.add(func); // Manda pro ArrayList
System.out.println("\n\n\nFuncionario cadastrado: \n" + func.toString()); //Mostra o que foi adicionado
System.in.read(); 
func.gravar(); //Salva em um txt
String[] separado = funcionarios.split(" "); //Aqui dá erro
```

Alguém sabe qual o erro?

Quero separar as infos cadastradas para cada funcionário (nome, e-mail, telefone, salário) em `String`s separadas.

Quero quebrar em `String`s para poder adicionar em um vetor, ordenar e depois poder criar um `ArrayList` ordenado por nome (em uma das opções da aplicação) ou salário (outra parte do código).

Obrigado

```
public String toString()
    {
        return    "\nNome: " + nome 
                + "\nEmail: " + email 
                + "\nTelefone: " + telefone 
                + "\nSalario: R$ " + salario ;
    }
```

Comment: Você quer uma lista de funcionários ou uma lista de nomes de funcionários?

Comment: Você deveria ter postado o erro. Mas neste caso, o erro é óbvio: não existe o método `ArrayList.split`.

Comment: Qual é a finalidade do `System.in.read();` isolado lá no meio?

Comment: O System.in.read(); é pra pausar a tela, senão passa direto. Esse processo tá dentro de um while

Comment: Você quer uma lista de funcionários ou uma lista de nomes de funcionários?

Comment: Opa @VictorStafusa Quero separar as infos cadastradas para cada funcionário (nome, e-mail, telefone, salário) em Strings separadas.

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer Isso muda completamente a sua pergunta. Neste caso, este tipo de informação deve estar presente no corpo da pergunta, caso contrário você acabará não recebendo as respostas que você procura.

Comment: Como é o método `toString()` da classe `Funcionario`?

Comment: Você quer 4 Arrays, um com os nomes outro com os e-mail etc?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Adicionei o toString() usado

Comment: @ramaral Isso. Quero quebrar em strings para poder adicionar em um vetor, ordenar e depois poder criar um ArrayList ordenado por nome (em uma das opções da aplicação) ou salário (outra parte do código).

Comment: Você já está a usar JAVA 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando separar um objeto com split(). Isso gera erro de compilação pois esse método separa apenas String.
Tenta isso `funcionarios.toString().split(" ");`, mas no split veja o que usar para separar.

Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```java
List<Funcionario> funcionarios = new ArrayList<>();
SortedSet<Funcionario> funcionariosPorNome = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Funcionario::getNome));
SortedSet<Funcionario> funcionariosPorSalario = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingDouble(Funcionario::getSalario));
SortedSet<Funcionario> funcionariosPorEmail = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Funcionario::getEmail));
SortedSet<Funcionario> funcionariosPorTelefone = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Funcionario::getTelefone));
```

```java
Funcionario func = new Funcionario(); //Instancio o obj
func.cadastrar();  //Chama o método que lê o teclado
funcionarios.add(func); // Manda pro ArrayList
System.out.println("\n\n\nFuncionario cadastrado: \n" + func.toString()); //Mostra o que foi adicionado
System.in.read(); 
func.gravar(); //Salva em um txt
funcionariosPorNome.add(func);
funcionariosPorSalario.add(func);
funcionariosPorEmail.add(func);
funcionariosPorTelefone.add(func);
```

Se não é isso que você quer, então por favor, edite a pergunta para deixar bem claro no texto o que é que você quer.

Answer (score 1):

Se o que quer é obter os funcionários ordenados por diferentes campos não precisa de fazer essas separações.
A partir duma `List<Funcionario>` é possível ordená-la como quiser.

```
List<Funcionario> funcionarios = new ArrayList<>();
func.cadastrar();  //CHama o método que lê o teclado
funcionarios.add(func); // Manda pro ArrayList
System.out.println("\n\n\nFuncionario cadastrado: \n" + func.toString()); //Mostra o que foi adicionado
System.in.read(); 
func.gravar(); //Salva em um txt
```

Ordena por nome:

```
Collections.sort(funcionarios, new Comparator<Funcionario>(){

    public int compare(Funcionario f1, Funcionario f2){

        return f1.nome.compareTo(f2.nome);

    }

});
```

Ordena por salário:

```
Collections.sort(funcionarios, new Comparator<Funcionario>(){

    public int compare(Funcionario f1, Funcionario f2){

        return f1.salario.compareTo(f2.salario);

    }

});
```

Comment: Perfeito, só que, infelizmente, não posso usar nenhum método sort. É um trabalho da faculdade. Perdão, esqueci de colocar isso no enunciado.

Comment: Com esse seu "esquecimento" fez com que, pelo menos, 2 pessoas perdessem 30 minutos do seu tempo.

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer Sinceramente, parece que você se esqueceu de colocar tudo no enunciado! Edita a pergunta e coloque lá tudo o que ela deve ter.

Comment: De boa, galera. Nem esquenta. Peço ao administrador para remover o tópico. Desculpe pela "perda de tempo". Não foi minha intenção. Obrigado